# Select value from table only if exist in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table one:

```
ID COLOR    
1  white 
2  red 
3  black 
4  blue 
5  yellow
```

Table two:

```
ID COLOR    
1  white 
2  white 
3  red 
4  black
```

Output should be:

```
1 white
2 red
3 black
```

(exclude 2 values that don't exist in second table - blue and yellow + exclude second white).

I tried different JOIN and EXIST queries, no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Two tables with same name. Isn't it serious violation of DB basics?

Comment: inner join will solve your problem.

Comment: I simplified my code. First table contains all categories (ID, Cat), second  one posts with assign categories (ID, Title, ...... Cat). I want to output (in the loop) only those categories which has posts and are not empty.

Comment: that comment makes no sense in the context of this question.

Answer (score 33):

`where exists` is appropriate for this.

```
select * 
  from t1
  where exists 
    (select 1
      from t2 where color = t1.color);
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e529/1)

The subquery is a correlated subquery (as it refers to a value from the other query), and as such it is executed for every row of the outer query.  So all the inner query needs to do, is check and see if the colour from the outer query (and first table) is present in the second table.

Comment: hi can you clear this problem of mine i want to clarify one thing i want the same thing as this i never done this before but let me ask you this for example i have 3 table; t1, t2, t3, i have inner join on them like t1.id inner join t2.id inner join t3.id my where would be where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 1 and t3.id = 3 problem is if the only does on exist in any table no result is return. what should be done in this problem

Comment: additional info i still want to select or fire the query even if it does not exist on other tables meaning i will only select from table where the id exists

Comment: sounds like you want to use `left join` instead of `inner join`. for any more info, try asking a question

Comment: Where Exists is is very slow query it took 19 seconds when I tried it. Left join is much much faster it took only 0.85 seconds in comparison.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.color = t2.color;
```

Just another way to get the same thing as @pala_

Comment: and I believe (someone correct me if I'm wrong please) but also more efficient as adding the clause on the join will reduce the number of records to be compared opposed to comparing all records in both tables

Comment: actually, this version will force the use of temporary tables thanks to the distinct - the `where exists` version wont. compare the explain plan [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d796c/1)

Comment: @dbinns66 . . . Incorrect.  The `exists` version should be more efficient.  It has no `select distinct`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it.  The DISTINCT was added to remove the duplicate white included in the join.  May be another way?

Comment: @gordon - I still believe the exists does an additiional  full table scan... it has to by definition